# Getting session error when using codeigniter inside glassfish

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, glassfish, quercus

I am using `glassfish4` server and codeigniter php framework.

I am new to glassfish server. I followed the oracle documentation for installing and configuring `glassfish4` with `quercus-4.0.1` and simple php scripts running well.

But when come to codeigniter framework, I got the following error:

> Message: Method call 'item' is not allowed for a null value.Filename:
>   libraries/Session.php

I am getting this error even after modified the session.php file. If I not invoke the session class, then this error will not show, but the whole frame will not work. Any solution?